# JAVA: Havel-Hakimi algorithm (Algorithm for determing whether the sequence of numbers can represent degrees of vertices in a graph)

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, graph

I want to write a code in java that helps you determin whether the numbers can represent degrees of vertices in a graph. We were told in the algorithmic graph theory class that there's a simple way to solve that with an algorithm that works like this:

1. You put the numbers in descending order

   ```
   3,3,2,1
   ```
2. Then you take the biggest one (in this case it's 3), 'erase it' (set it to zero in an array, I guess) and then from n-following numbers subtract 1 (n equals the value of this biggest number, in this case you subtract one from the following 3 numbers)

   ```
   0,2,1,0
   ```

If needed, put the numbers in descending order once again and repeat the algorithm, erase the biggest number and subtract 1 from n-following numbers.

Do this until you either:

a) come across negative number(s), in which case it means that your sequence of numbers cannot represent degrees of vertices in a graph *or*

b) you are at the end of your algorithm and all the numbers are zeroes which means that these numbers can represent degrees of vertices in a graph

For these particular numbers it should go like this

```
3,3,2,1
0,2,1,0
0,0,0,-1
```

And as there's -1, it means that this sequence of numbers couldn't represent degrees of vertices in a graph.

So far my code for the algorithm and checking whether it is done looks like this (I already have the main method with scanner in it so the user can write down how many vertices and what degrees he wants to find out about, this is just where I don't know what to do next):

```
public void alg() {

        int size = this.vertices.length;
        do  {
            this.check();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                int biggest = i;
                int max = this.vertices[biggest];
                this.vertices[biggest] = 0; 

                for (int j = 0; j <= max + 1; j++) {
                    this.vertices[j+1]--;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.vertices)); 
                    biggest++;
                } 

            }         
        } while (this.finished != true);
    }    

    public void check() {
        Integer[] zeroes = new Integer[this.vertices.length];
        Arrays.fill(zeroes, 0); //this probably isn't necessary
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.vertices.length; i++) {
            if (this.vertices[i] < 0) {
                this.finished = true;
                System.out.println("not a graph");
            } 
            if(this.vertices[i] == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (Arrays.equals(this.vertices, zeroes)) {
            System.out.println("a graph");
        }
    }
```

So if the user's sequence of numbers is 3,3,2,1, the programme will print out only this and won't continue

```
[3, 3, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
```

I guess I'm missing something in the loops but I can't figure out what. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I believe you're looking into the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) - I don't know enough about it to help with your specific code, but you might want to edit your question to include the name of it in the title or body to get more views and specialised answers. There's some good examples of it [here](http://coddicted.com/the-havel-hakimi-algorithm/)  which may help you out :-)

Comment: Two big things, 1. check your loop conditions, and 2. check to see if you actually set `finished` to true everywhere you should. I'm too lazy to type up a full answer but these hints should help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in your inner `for` loop. In your example it runs from `j = 0` to `j = 4`.

Inside the loop you try to access `this.vertices[j+1]` which would be at the end of this loop the 5th entry of this array. You should get an exception by the Java Runtime here.

The second problem is, that you always start at the first index of you array.

Try changing this for loop to

```
for (int j = i+1; j <= max + i ; j++) {
        this.vertices[j]--;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.vertices)); 
        biggest++;
}
```

Comment: Additionally you end up in a infinite loop if the sequence of numbers does represent degrees of vertices. In this case you should add ` this.finished = true;` to your `check()` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that even if max is 8 the array size could be 3, so you would get an IndexOutOfBoundsException using just max as a stop condition for the for j loop. What you need to use is min(max,size).

Comment: @chillichief is right about the problem with the initialization of j too. You need to start from i + 1. And the finished flag when finding all zeros. For that check you can avoid the Arrays.equals() and just check if count equals the array size.